# Ticket Wording - tag

Tags: united-states, georgia

I received a $170 ticket for a 6 month expired tag on my car in Sandy Springs. (Miscommunication in my family about my tag - realize in the end that it was my fault for not making sure my tag was up to date myself so no argument there.) The ticket says “no tag” instead of “expired tag”. Is this correct or say something? I also think they overcharged me according to Fulton County ticket charge schedule.

Comment: Expired tag and no tag are the same thing - they're both the absence of a valid tag.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot advise you to pay the fine or contest it, but we can say that the law is. A notation like "no tag" is not the same as a formal charge that would be filed against you if you were prosecuted, under [Georgia Code 40-2-8](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2014/title-40/chapter-2/article-1/section-40-2-8). The law says

> (b)(2)(A) It shall be a misdemeanor to operate any vehicle required to
>   be registered in the State of Georgia without a valid numbered license
>   plate properly validated, unless such operation is otherwise permitted
>   under this chapter

Hence driving with expired tags is against the law. [The state indicates](https://dor.georgia.gov/motor-vehicles-fees-fines-and-penalties) that the penalty for non-renewal is "10% of Ad Valorem Tax due + 25% of License Plate Fees", the latter being $20. There is also a fine of $25 for operating a vehicle without a valid county decal; you presumably know what the current ad valorem tax on the vehicle is.